# How to override a Json Writer in Ext Js 4.2.0

Tags: extjs

I'm a newbie in the Ext Js 4.2 area, I needed to save one model having hasMany associations, I found the solution (by overriding the Json Writer) here

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store/page4

but I have no idea where to put the file containing the overriding function, and how to make it work. Anyone so kind to explain it to me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the file in Script folder and make the implementation of has many association in a method.

just like:

var hasManyAssociation = function(){

// write your code here...........

}

now you can call the function where it needs.